# Sharing entity data model between website and windows service projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a solution which contain two projects. One is website project in MVC using Entity Framework 6 and other is windows service project.

Entity data model (edmx), connection string as well as all other settings are defined in web.config of website project. Now I want to use the same data model in windows service project. Is this possible?

I added website project as reference in windows service project but it gave me error that I should define all web.config connection string as well as settings in app.config. I did that but still it is not working as now it is expecting entity data model.

Even if I use a method which is defined in a class of website project, and use that metho in windows service project, it still gives error because that method references entity data model which is not present in windows service.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: create a class library project with your data entities, add reference to this library from both website and windows service projects. And add all settings in both web.config and app.config

Comment: Thanks. It worked.